# What happens to a summoned mount when they reach 0 HP?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

What happens when a summoned horse is reduced to 0 or less hp? Does it vanish? Or can it be healed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All summoned creatures that are summoned from a summoning-type spell (conjuration, sub-school summoning), when reduced to 0 or fewer hit points, are returned to their origin location.  This rule information is under the Conjuration (summoning) sub-school rules:

> Summoning: a summoning spell instantly brings a creature or object to
>   a place you designate. When the spell ends or is dispelled, a summoned
>   creature is instantly sent back to where it came from, but a summoned
>   object is not sent back unless the spell description specifically
>   indicates this. **A summoned creature also goes away if it is killed or
>   if its hit points drop to 0 or lower, but it is not really dead. It
>   takes 24 hours for the creature to reform, during which time it can't
>   be summoned again**.  (PRD, *[Magic: School -- Conjuration](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Conjuration)*)